# Microsoft Excel: pivot without aggregation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel (office 365) on mac, I want to group data by a specific column value, as in a pivot table, but without aggregating it.
As an example, i would like to transform:

```
A 2
B 1
A 3
B 4
```

to:

```
A B
2 1
3 4
```

I've tried using pivot tables, but those seem to require some form of aggregation, which I don't want. I only want to list these values.

Comment: VBA should be no problem, formulas might be doable with various combinations of `UNIQUE` `TRANSPOSE` `FILTER` and/or `XLOOKUP`. If you are still stuck after using these, then come back and edit your question with where you are stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Can you add an auxiliary column with a,b,c,d... and pivot the new table?

Comment: @gns100 Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that? I'm completely new to excel, so I don't really know that those functions do. At this point i'm sort of befuddled why this is so hard.

Comment: If you are new to excel, then I suggest the semi-manual way of filtering your existing data, then copy-paste that result to a new worksheet. Repeat that for every category. If yo are interested in learning formulas type in those that I gave you and see what they do. In the end, we can only give general advice to general questions.

Comment: Yes, your advice was very helpful! I ended up moving to google sheets, since their functions have stable names despite OS language. With that, i managed to solve the issue by using the filter function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in `M1:N4`:

```
P1: =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($M$1:$M$4))
P2: =FILTER($N$1:$N$4,$M$1:$M$4=P$1)
```

Select `P2` and drag/fill right to `Q2`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i wanted!